# Как поменять имя таблицы для регистрации?

Tags: laravel

Для регистрации нового пользователя(админа) меняю название таблицы с **users** на **admins**. При регистрации через форму, при **Validator::make()** выдаёт что нету такой таблицы(**users**) ошибка только при проверке.
Если же я создаю в базе ещё одну таблицу(**users**), то проверка проходит но все данные записываются в таблицу(**admins**).

---

Вопрос почему при **Validator::make()** не проверяет таблицу(**admins**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
}
```

Нужно изменить название таблицы:

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:admins',
```

PS: В ларавель младше 5.3 валидатор находится в app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php

Comment: Спасибо, благодарен